# Inheriting from a singleton class considerations

Tags: c#, inheritance, singleton

I have a `singleton` logger which is used by many threads at run-time for logging purposes. I need different types of it so I decided to move changeable part into `protected` methods and inherit from it.

Is there anything special with `singleton` classes in inheritance (any considerations we don't have with regular classes)?

Comment: wouldn't the inherited class use the constructor of the parent hence return the parent class on new()

Comment: My question is - why are you trying to inherit from a singleton?

Comment: @William: For example if the child wants to change the log file format. This logger adds some data to each log like from where the logging has been done (assembly, namespace, class, method). I made it singleton so logging with one line of code is possible: `Logger.Log.info("Hello World!")`

Comment: If you look at log4net for instance, this is done setting properties or strategies in the singleton itself. this seems more effective to me. See http://log4net.sourceforge.net/release/1.2.0.30316/doc/manual/faq.html#customLayouts

Comment: Is your Singleton logger a static class, if it is then I don't think you should be inheriting it. I agree with Mario, you should look at something like log4net or Nlog etc.

Comment: Well bottom line - inheriting from a Singleton makes no sense. Singletons rely on the fact that only the singleton class itself can create an instance. If you can have one derived class creating an instance of itself, you can have multiple derived classes, thus breaking the purpose of the Singleton.

Comment: Agree with the others that you shouldn't be inheriting from a singleton.  Look at the singleton design pattern here: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx It's marked as sealed to prevent you from inheriting from it.

Answer (score 1):

Singletons should be sealed, period. Otherwise they may not really be singletons in practice.

Of course you may use an IOC container such as StructureMap, Autofac or Castle Windsor to manage the lifestyle of your class; then you don't have to write it as a singleton, just declare it in the IOC container as a singleton.

That being said, looking at your particular example (you want logging), you may not really need a singleton class for that. You only use singleton if there is a very good reason to -- such as severe overhead when creating the object. But opening a text file for writing does not count as significant overhead...

Comment: Ok for the overhead, but concurrent access to a file justifies a singleton for me.

Comment: For concurrent write access to a file, you need to either implement queueing or create a critical section with locking. There can be no such thing as concurrent write access to a file.